# How to see if string matches any regex keys in ruby hash

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

I have a JSON file full of regex keys with responses based on the message  sent (eg. Hello, Dragnflier!). The file contains values like this:

```
{
  "/hello/i" : "Why hello there!", 
  "/how are you.*dragnflier/i" : "I'm good thank you! How are you?"
}
```

I load these into a hash at the start of my ruby program. Is there a more efficient way to see if the message matches any of the regular expressions in my hash than just running a loop over it with all of the keys? I want to get the value that the key returns, not a list of keys or a boolean value.

Comment: You didn't post your code. We can't guess at the performance of code we can't see ;-)

Comment: As the question states, I was just using a loop. Loops are generally the most inefficient way to search through data. For reference, it was just commands.keys.each do |key| .... that broke the loop when it found a match in the case I wanted one result, or continued to the end if I wanted multiple.

Comment: Well, in my experience using a "description" of code can lead to great confusion and miscommunication. You say "just a foo", but I might interpret is as "just a FOO". Besides, to archive a "base-line" for testing all people wanting to answer this now have to write a loop. Why not do that work for us? ;-)

Comment: fair point. It was meant to be more of a general question, rather than a specific one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution ended up being, based on other answers for the opposite case:

```
val = myhash.keys.select {|key| message.to_s.match(key)}
```

Comment: If you just want to know if any of the regexes match (and don't care which one(s)), use `any?` instead of `select`. It will return `true` as soon as it finds a match, or `false` if it finds none.

Comment: Hi Jordan, I wanted to get the value from that key back, not just see if any exist. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This answer returns an array, by the way. Use `detect` to return the first match.

Comment: that wasn't part of the question.

Comment: Note that `message.to_s.match(Regexp.new(key))` can simply be `message.to_s.match(key)` b/c `key` is already a `Regexp` object, based on the hash being used

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is more efficient way:

```
hash = {
  /hello/i => "Why hello there!", 
  /how are you.*dragnflier/i => "I'm good thank you! How are you?"
}
message =~ Regexp.union(hash.keys)
```

You stated that the goal is to check “if the message matches any of the regular expressions in my hash.” The above is way more efficient than the solution you came up with.

After this preliminary check is done, one might do whatever she wants to detect the respective key (this claim appeared in the questions after I have it answered.) This approach will be more efficient than just bruteforce `detect` on keys.

Please note, that the answer you have provided is not correct, since

```
Regexp.new '/foo/i'
```

becomes

```
#⇒ /\/foo\/i/i
```

and not

```
#⇒ /foo/i
```

as you probably expected.

Comment: Hi mudasobwa, please see my changes to the question, I felt like the scenario clarified I wanted the value, not just if there were keys that matched the case. I have fixed my answer, I removed the /i from all of my values in my hash to save readability and prevent issues if the /i is forgotten. In all cases in my program, I always want it to be case insensitive.

Comment: beautiful answer but I'm thinking it is not more efficient. in my experience, union was slower than simply iterating over an array of regular expressions even in the case where the union is reused for multiple queries. your code could and should faster if the underlying implementation were fixed. ASIDE: I tend to want the value out of the hash and not an `exists?`